# Extracting text with selenium by ID

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to extract text using selenium in Python from an html. My text is under the id tag and when I try to retrieve the text this way gives me error.

[image]

```
date=browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblIncDate')
date2=date.text
date1.append(date)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-20d6df14a340> in <module>()
     37 date1.append(date)
     38 userid_element = browser.find_elements_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblIncDate')
---> 39 userid = userid_element.text
     40 userid1.append(userid)
     41 time.sleep(20)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Also,
I tried with xpath but does not really work:

```
date2=date.text
date1.append(date)
```

```
  File "<ipython-input-19-8b8e7fb86782>", line 35
    date=browser.find_element_by_xpath(''//span[@id= 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblIncDate' ]'')
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't presented the failing code, but from the traceback it's visible that you're using plural version (browser.find_element**s**_by_id) instead of singular `browser.find_element_by_id`.

Comment: Plus their other error where they needed " not ' i.e. date=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id= 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblIncDate']")

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the text **4/20/2016** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located` and you can use either of the followingcan use [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblIncDate"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblIncDate']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```